# Pushing metadata automatically in Git

Tags: geonetwork

I want to make a connection between Geonode and Geonetwork.
 I want to harvest the metadata from Geonetwork.
How to connect Geonode to Geonetwork?
please guide me

Comment: What does Git have to do in this question?